# Run sql query in if statement shell script

Tags: mysql, sql, shell

I am trying to run sql query in if statement. Here is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

var="select col1, col2 from table_name where condition;"

    count=$(ping -c 4 192.168.7.204 | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')

      if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then

        mysql -h 192.168.7.204 -u username -ppassword db_name<<EOFMYSQL
        $var
        EOFMYSQL

      fi
```

But it shows me an error

```
./test.sh: line 18: warning: here-document at line 12 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOFMYSQL')
./test.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The here-document sentinel`EOFMYSQL`  has to be up against the left margin, not indented:

```
var="select col1, col2 from table_name where condition;"

count=$(ping -c 4 192.168.7.204 | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')

if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then    
    mysql -h 192.168.7.204 -u username -ppassword db_name <<EOFMYSQL
$var
EOFMYSQL    
fi
```

If you change the `<<EOFMYSQL` to `<<-EOFMYSQL` you can indent it, as long as you use only tabs and not spaces.

See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

Comment: I am sorry but i don't have much knowledge of it. I am learning sql and shell script too. Can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: I mean you can't have any space on the line before `EOFMYSQL`.  It has to be the very first thing on the line.

Comment: In this simple case, you don't need a *HERE* document. Which shell are you using?

Comment: @user1934428 I tried without using `EOFMYSQL` It shows no error but nothing in output. So how do i get to know whether sql query run or not? If run then where is output?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using EOFMYSQL"? Post your modified code .... BTW, I asked which shell you are using. It's difficult to discuss the "best" way to solve the problem, without knowing this.

Comment: @user1934428 created script in bash. And without `EOFMYSQL` means i only run `mysql -h 192.168.7.204 -u username -ppassword db_name
        $var` and i think this might be wrong.

Comment: It is. mysql expects the Query from standard input. In bash (or zsh), you would have to write this as `<<<$var`. See the paragraph named *Here Strings* in the bash man page.